# Get values of views inside listview item on click

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview containing different xml layouts, each with different views. I was wondering how I can get the data from the views inside the item that the user has clicked on, inside the `onItemClick` method.

My listview is made up of multiple layouts so I cannot know for sure which layout is being pressed when the onItemClick method is called. For example, one of the items in the layouts in the listview is:

```
// list_item.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where as another layout in the listview could be:

```
// list_item_name.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="28sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So I am at a loss as to how to get the data for all these views for any layout within the listview.

My previous attempt was this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {            
    Object obj = adapter.getItem(position);
    String value = obj.toString();
}
```

However `value` in this instance, returns a string containing all the values of all the views inside this item, for example: `{caption=MobileNumber, value=07000123456}` <<< I cannot do anything with this string unless I try and pick it apart using `substring`, which is unreliable at best considering the values may have been created by the user.

This is my adapter in use (credit to [Jeff Sharkey](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/), I did not create this adapter):

```
public class SeparatedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  

    public final Map<String,Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String,Adapter>();  
    public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;  
    public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;  

    public SeparatedListAdapter(Context context) {  
        headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header);  
    }  

    public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) {  
        this.headers.add(section);  
        this.sections.put(section, adapter);  
    }
    public void addSectionNoHeader(String section, Adapter adapter) {
        this.sections.put(section, adapter);
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return section;  
            if(position < size) return adapter.getItem(position - 1);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    public int getCount() {  
        // total together all sections, plus one for each section header  
        int total = 0;  
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())  
            total += adapter.getCount() + 1;  
        return total;  
    }  

    public int getViewTypeCount() {  
        // assume that headers count as one, then total all sections  
        int total = 1;  
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())  
            total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();  
        return total;  
    }  

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {  
        int type = 1;  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;  
            if(position < size) return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
            type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();  
        }  
        return -1;  
    }  

    public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() {  
        return false;  
    }  

    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {  
        return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        int sectionnum = 0;  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);  
            if(position < size) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
            sectionnum++;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public long getItemId(int position) {  
        return position;  
    }  

}
```

I'm looking for a way of extracting the values of *all* the views inside the item. But the fact that the item that has been clicked could be one of any layouts is confusing me. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here is an example of how I am using this adapter in code:

```
SeparatedListAdapter adapter;
Customer cust;
ListView lvDetails;

public Map<String,?> createDoubleItem(String title, String caption) {  
        Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();  
        item.put(ITEM_VALUE, title);  
        item.put(ITEM_CAPTION, caption);  
        return item;  
    }

    public Map<String,?> createSingleItem(String name) {  
        Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();  
        item.put(ITEM_VALUE, name);
        return item;
    } 

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_customer);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        cust = Db.Functions.getCustomer(intent.getStringExtra("uuid"));
        lvDetails = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custdetails);
        adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);
        lvDetails.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Gen.popup("Item clicked");
            }
        });

        // Name
        List<Map<String,?>> name = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();
        if (cust.firstName == null && cust.lastName == null)
            name.add(createSingleItem("Unnamed Customer"));
        else
            name.add(createSingleItem(
                    ((cust.title != null) ? cust.title + " " : "") +
                    ((cust.firstName != null) ? cust.firstName + " " : "") +
                    ((cust.lastName != null) ? cust.lastName : "")));
        adapter.addSection("Name", new SimpleAdapter(this, name, R.layout.list_item_name,   
                new String[] { ITEM_VALUE },
                new int[] { R.id.lblName }));
        // Phones
        if ((cust.mobileNumber != null || cust.homeNumber != null || cust.workNumber != null) && SHOW_PHONES)
        {
            List<Map<String,?>> phone = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();
            if (cust.mobileNumber != null)
                phone.add(createDoubleItem(cust.mobileNumber, "Mobile"));
            if (cust.homeNumber != null)
                phone.add(createDoubleItem(cust.homeNumber, "Home"));
            if (cust.workNumber != null)
                phone.add(createDoubleItem(cust.workNumber, "Work"));
            adapter.addSection("Phone", new SimpleAdapter(this, phone, R.layout.list_item,   
                    new String[] { ITEM_VALUE, ITEM_CAPTION },
                    new int[] { R.id.lblSub, R.id.lblMain }));
        }  
        lvDetails.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of data do you store in your Adapter? Just cast the getItem() to your data type and use methods to access the fields.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following you. I have edited my question to make it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first off the link you provided for that adapter looks like it was very old (2008, 5 years ago) I'd look at a 3rd party library like [this](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)

but that's besides the point.

the design of the adapter is very convoluted as there's multiple adapters in it so I can't be sure how this will work without spinning up my own test project.

now when you call in onItemClick you want to add the following

```
int viewType = adapter.getItemViewType(position);
if (viewType == SeparatedListAdapter.TYPE_SECTION_HEADER) {
    //header clicked handle that here maybe do nothing
} else {
    Map<String,?> clickedItem = (Map<String,?>) adapter.getItem(position);
    String value = (String) clickedItem.Get(ITEM_VALUE);
    String caption = (String) clickedItem.Get(ITEM_CAPTION);
    //here you can do things with the clicked item
    //also because you know the view type you can find other views on it
}
```

Edit: adjusted what the onclick should look like based on what you provided

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm not understanding you that well. I'm not sure what `MyClass` represents here, or what I should put in it. I've edited my question to include an example of how I'm using this adapter in code.